# JMockit 1.31 with JUnit 5.0.0-M4 NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, jmockit, junit5

Following code gives NullPointerException in Expectations block on line `myInterface.method(anyInt); result = 1;`.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public int method(int x);
}

public class MyClass {
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    public int method() {
        return myInterface.method(5);
    }
}

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Capturing
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    @Test
    void testing() {
        new Expectations() {{
            myInterface.method(anyInt); result = 1;
        }};

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myInterface);
        assertEquals(1, myClass.method());
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyClassTest$1.<init>(MyClassTest.java:18)
at MyClassTest.testing(MyClassTest.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(MethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:81)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
at org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.run(JUnitPlatform.java:132)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I understood correctly, JMockit should make some kind of proxy object that implements `MyInterface`, but variable `myInterface` is `null`. Do I need additional steps to "initialize" `myInterface` variable. I also tried with `@Mocked` and `@Injectable` annotations but I got same results.

**UPDATE:**
Code works fine with JUnit 5 M1, M2 and M3.

**UPDATE:**
JMockit 1.36 with JUnit 5.0.2 works as expected.

Comment: Does it work with an older milestone of JUnit 5?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with M1, M2 and M3 and it works with all three. It seems something is changed in M4 or there is a bug.

Comment: @MarcPhilipp  Not sure is this JUnit or JMockit issue but I opened an issue on JMockit github.

Comment: @JosipVujcic What was the issue number for the JMockit issue you opened?

Comment: @Thunderforge 412

Comment: @JosipVujcic Looks like this issue is fixed for JMockit 1.32. Would you like to add an answer to this question explaining that?

Comment: @Thunderforge I'll try 1.32 when it is officially released and add an answer if the issue is fixed.